WriteFile(hInputWrite, ...) has no effect C++
I'm making a program in C++ that makes use of a pseudo-terminal using ConPTY.exe to create interactive terminal sessions. My write method to the pty is not working.
In pty.cpp, the Pty::write method takes one string argument, data. The goal of the method is to write to the pseudo-terminal console. I.e. the WriteFile method (in pty.cpp:108) is supposed to write data to pty. However, the onData method receives a function that's called whenever the pty data is modified, but it doesn't trigger.
I tried googling a lot of stuff but I could get no result which could solve my problem. Even my code has no error, which makes me confused.
pty.h:
#ifndef PTY_H
#define PTY_H

#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

class Pty {
public:
    Pty(COORD size);
    ~Pty();
    
    bool spawn(const std::wstring& command, const std::wstring& cmdline);
    //std::string read();
    void onData(const std::function<void(const std::string&)>& callback);
    void write(const std::string& data);
    void resize(COORD size);
    void close();

private:
    HANDLE hInputRead = NULL;
    HANDLE hInputWrite = NULL;
    HANDLE hOutputRead = NULL;
    HANDLE hOutputWrite = NULL;
    HPCON hPC = NULL;

    std::function<void(const std::string&)> dataCallback;
    std::thread readThread;
    void readLoop();
};

#endif // !PTY_H

pty.cpp:
#include "pty.h"
#include <iostream>

Pty::Pty(COORD size) {
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), NULL, TRUE };
    if (!CreatePipe(&hOutputRead, &hOutputWrite, &sa, 0) ||
        !CreatePipe(&hInputRead, &hInputWrite, &sa, 0)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create pipes" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "Pipes created. " << hInputRead << " && - && " << hInputWrite << std::endl;
    if (CreatePseudoConsole(size, hInputRead, hOutputWrite, 0, &hPC) != S_OK) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create pseudo console" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}

Pty::~Pty() {
    close();
}

bool Pty::spawn(const std::wstring& command, const std::wstring& cmdline)
{
    STARTUPINFOEX siEx;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&siEx, sizeof(siEx));

    siEx.StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siEx);
    siEx.StartupInfo.hStdInput = hInputRead;
    siEx.StartupInfo.hStdOutput = hOutputWrite;
    siEx.StartupInfo.hStdError = hOutputWrite;    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    siEx.StartupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    // extra env setup
    WCHAR env[] = L"TERM=xterm-256color\0";
    LPWCH lpEnvironment = (LPWCH)malloc(sizeof(env));
    memcpy(lpEnvironment, env, sizeof(env));

    SIZE_T attrSize = 0;
    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(NULL, 1, 0, &attrSize);
    siEx.lpAttributeList = (LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)malloc(attrSize);
    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(siEx.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, &attrSize);
    UpdateProcThreadAttribute(siEx.lpAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PSEUDOCONSOLE, hPC, sizeof(hPC), NULL, NULL);

    BOOL success = CreateProcessW(NULL, const_cast<LPWSTR>(cmdline.c_str()), NULL, NULL, TRUE, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, lpEnvironment, NULL, &siEx.StartupInfo, &pi);

    if (!success) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to spawn process" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    free(lpEnvironment);
    return true;
}

void Pty::onData(const std::function<void(const std::string&)>& callback)
{
    dataCallback = callback;
    //readThread = std::thread(&Pty::readLoop, this);
    if (!readThread.joinable()) {
        readThread = std::thread(&Pty::readLoop, this);
    }
}

void Pty::readLoop()
{
    char buffer[256];
    DWORD read;
    /*while (ReadFile(hOutputRead, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL) && read > 0) {
        buffer[read] = '\0';
        std::string data(buffer);
        if (dataCallback) {
            dataCallback(data);
        }
    }*/
    while (true) {
        BOOL result = ReadFile(hOutputRead, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &read, NULL);

        if (!result || read == 0) {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) {
                std::cerr << "Read failed: Pipe was closed" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "Read failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        }

        buffer[read] = '\0';
        std::string data(buffer, read);
        std::cout << "test - pty data: " << data << std::endl;
        if (dataCallback) {
            dataCallback(data);
        }
    }
}

void Pty::write(const std::string& data) {
    if (hInputWrite == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Write Failed: Input handle is NULL" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    DWORD written = 0;
    BOOL success = WriteFile(hInputWrite, data.c_str(), data.size(), &written, NULL);

    if (success) {
        FlushFileBuffers(hInputWrite);
    }

    if (!success || written != data.size()) {
        std::cerr << "Write failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Successfully wrote to PTY: " << data << std::endl;
    }
}

void Pty::resize(COORD size) {
    if (hPC) {
        ResizePseudoConsole(hPC, size);
    }
}

void Pty::close() {
    if (readThread.joinable()) {
        readThread.join();
    }

    if (hPC) ClosePseudoConsole(hPC);
    CloseHandle(hOutputRead);
    CloseHandle(hOutputWrite);
    CloseHandle(hInputRead);
    CloseHandle(hInputWrite);
    hPC = NULL;
}

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "pty.h"
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    COORD size = { 80, 24 };
    Pty pty(size);

    pty.spawn(L"cmd.exe", L"cmd.exe");

    pty.write("echo Hello, World!\r\n"); // This write method doesn't work.

    pty.onData([](const std::string& data) {
        std::cout << "pty data: " << data << std::endl;
    });

    pty.close();
    
    return 0;
}

Whenever I call the write method, it always prints out a successful message, but it takes no effect.

"not working" -- Please be more specific about the symptoms or else I will assume your program caused a power spike that took your local power station offline. What did you observe, and what did you expect?

"Even my code has no error" -- This means that your code is working perfectly, and you have no reason to post a question here. Possibly you meant your code has no syntax errors? Which would narrow down a little what "not working" is supposed to mean, but is still far from any sort of assurance that your code is error-free.

@JaMiT in pty.cpp Pty::write method takes one string argument thats data. the goal of the method is to write to the pseudo-terminal console i.e. the the WriteFile method (in pty.cpp:108) is supposed to write data to pty. but here, the onData method recieves a type of function thats called whenever the pty data is modified - but it doesnt trigger. (I'm kinda new to C++)

Where is the code that actually uses the Pty class? Please provide a [mcve]

I am getting confused about what you expect and what you are trying to do. You don't indicate what program you are trying to act as a terminal for. More to the point, you don't indicate how you have determined that the program you are attempting to provide "keyboard input" to isn't receiving that input. Have you seen this post: Problem with using CreatePseudoConsole . . . ? Apologies if I'm off base, I'm not familiar with this pty stuff.

@RemyLebeau here is the code to reproduce it: https://gist.github.com/GlitchieTheDev/ec7615b1e7795f3708bc5a6bfbc31e10

@AviBerger Thanks for sharing that post with me, I'll check it out and see if that helps me. I'm not fimiliar with these pty things too, infact im new to cpp

@GlitchieTheDev StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Posts are expected to be self-contained so they can be useful to future readers. Posting links to code hosted on external sites is discouraged as links break over time. I have copied your main code into your question.

@GlitchieTheDev Information in comments does not count as part of the question, so I've copied (slightly edited) your comment into your question. Stlll, line 108??? That's a lot of lines for a [mre]. How much code could you remove if your goal was not a fully functional terminal but a demonstration of how invoking write("Hi") should (but doesn't) invoke the callback? Drop everything else -- don't even pretend you're working on a terminal -- and focus on this one data channel.
